# truncating and padding an integer

Tags: java, integer, padding, truncate

I'm working with variable integer lengths. For each I need to simply have the rightmost two numbers. e.g:

```
3938   = 38
787028 = 28
83883  = 83
```

The other numbers don't matter, I just need the two rightmost integer. 
Also, I'm working under the assumption that some numbers will be single digit. For these numbers, I will need to pad them with an extra left zero. e.g:

```
8 = 08
2 = 02
```

Thanks

Comment: `String.format("%02d", n % 100)`

Comment: @JoopEggen Why didn't you just make this an answer?

Comment: @SteveP I commented as I felt the question formulated a bit non-mathematically. I intended others to answer and explain; modulo and such.

Comment: @JoopEggen Fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int foo = 3938;
int modulo = foo % 100;
String formatted = String.format("%02d", modulo);
```